# XPath works only for some site

Tags: python, xpath, python-requests, lxml

I'm starting with XPath from lxml.

I'm only write some instruction, but I noticed that XPath works only for some site.

I try to Explain:

If I test this code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

URL = 'https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagina_principale'
page = requests.get(URL)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

items = tree.xpath('//div[@id="mw-navigation"]//text()')
print(items)
```

The result is all the text in the div with the id="mw-navigation".

Does anyone know why, if I have this other site with this HTML (checked with the inspector):

```
<a id="text-search-submit">
 <span>Search</span>
</a>
```

and with this code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

URL = 'https://www.sneakersnstuff.com/en/472/upcoming-releases'
page = requests.get(URL)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

items = tree.xpath('//a[@id="text-search-submit"]//text()')
print(items)
```

items is empty?

Comment: Please provide website you're working with

Comment: I'm getting a captcha when trying to access that url via requests `<title>Sneakersnstuff - Man or machine</title>`. Hence why the search element does not exist

Comment: How did u get this captcha? Can u post the code?

Comment: It is not that @cullzie is generating a Captcha. It is that when you request the website it directs you to a Captcha to prove that you're human - unfortunately you code is not! If you manually go to the site and complete the Captcha and then get the source your XPath works fine. In your first example you target Wikipedia who don't protect that particular page from Bots

Comment: @GennaroLimite I got the captcha when I ran the code you provided. Check the response code on your page variable. In mine it was showing as `<Response [403]>`